# Factory Girl Issue with create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, tdd, factory-bot

Why does the following placed in `spec/factories.rb` give me the error out put bellow:

```
FactoryGirl.create :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@example.com" }
  f.password "test"
end
```

Error:

```
`find': Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `define` instead of `create` in factories.rb. Like this

```
FactoryGirl.define :user do |f|
```

Then in the tests, you use `create`